# Calculate longest consecutive period based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the longest freezing period from .csv file. I can access the temperature with `data["TX"]`. For the line `if data["TX"] < 0` I somehow keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I solve this problem?

```
import pandas as pd
with open("klimaat.csv") as f:
    counter = 0
    freeze = 0
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        if data["TX"] < 0:
            counter += 1
        if data["TX"] >= 0:
            if counter > freeze:
                freeze = counter
                counter = 0
            else:
                counter = 0
    print(freeze)
```

A piece of the data file ("TX" is the temperature in Celsius, times 10):

```
STAID   SOUID   DATE    TX  Q_TX
162 100522  19010101    -31 0
162 100522  19010102    -13 0
162 100522  19010103    -5  0
162 100522  19010104    -10 0
162 100522  19010105    -18 0
162 100522  19010106    -78 0
162 100522  19010107    -66 0
162 100522  19010108    -6  0 
162 100522  19010109    42  0
```

Comment: Where's your data? You can use pandas vectorised functions for this, don't use a loop.

Comment: I just added a piece of the data file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data["TX"] < 0` gives you a mask. Make use of this to find the longest sequence of sub-zero temperatures.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("klimaat.csv")

i = data['TX'] < 0
j = i.ne(i.shift()).cumsum()

freeze = j[i].value_counts().max()
```

The trick here is to get all consecutive groups of `True` values (corresponding to sub-zero temperatures) and find the largest group.

```
print(freeze)
8
```

---

**Details**

```
i

0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8    False
Name: TX, dtype: bool


j[i]

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    1
Name: TX, dtype: int64


j[i].value_counts()

1    8
Name: TX, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @JohnDoe I added the full code listing. Read the CSV into a dataframe, you can ditch your current code. Take care of delimiters.

Comment: Do you know how to also print the last 'i' value, ie. the date when the longest freezing period ends? And what does the 'i.ne()' part mean

Comment: @JohnDoe Maybe `data.iloc[j[j == j[i].value_counts().idxmax()].index[-1]]`?

Comment: I know I can access the date by using 'data["DATE"]. Your method gives me the whole line, now I only want the DATE

Comment: @JohnDoe `data.loc[j[j == j[i].value_counts().idxmax()].index[-1], 'date']`

Comment: One last thing, could you please explain what these pieces of code do: i.ne(i.shift()).cumsum() and data.loc[j[j == j[i].value_counts().idxmax()].index[-1], 'date']

Comment: `i.ne(i.shift()).cumsum()` will put each consecutive group of values into a labelled group. `j[i].value_counts().max()` counts the number of items of each group and finds the max.

Comment: Similarly, `j[i].value_counts().idxmax()` gets the index of the max value, uses that to index back into `j` which in turn will index back into `data`.